# Convergence in distribution criteria

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Suppose we have a sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ and the law of each $X_n$ is supported by $\{1,2,...,n\}$. Hence, we can assume that they are all $\mathbb{N}$-valued random variables.

If we like to prove that the sequence $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ converges in distribution to the dirac measure at $\{1\}$, i.e. that $\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$, would it be sufficient to show that $ \mathbb{P}(X_n=n-k) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ for $k\in \{0,1,...,n-2\}$ ? The growing support is what bothers me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:** $\Bbb P(X_n=k)={1\over n}$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$. (That is, $X_n$ is uniformly distributed over $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.)